# Is there a more reliable drop-in replacement for mimetypes.guess_extension()?

Tags: python, mime-types

I'm up against the following (Python 2.7.10 on Ubuntu Trusty):

```
>>> from mimetypes import guess_extension
>>> guess_extension('text/html')
'.html'
>>> guess_extension('application/json')
'.json'
>>> guess_extension('text/plain')
'.ksh'
>>> guess_extension('audio/mp3')
>>>
```

It got text/html and application/json right, made a bad guess for text/plain, and gave me nothing for audio/mp3. (Interestingly, changing the last one to audio/mpeg returns `'.mp3'` as expected, but that's not what my data source uses.)

Is there a more reliable alternative to this module that would return `'.txt'` and `'.mp3'` in my last two cases? I looked into python-magic, but based on everything I saw it looks like it needs to read the actual file data to function. In my case, all I have is the MIME type as a string.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with a fix set of mimetypes that `guess_extension` is getting wrong, put an override dictionary ahead of the guess.

```
known_extension = {'text/html': '.txt', ...}
...
extension = known_extension.get(mimetype) or guess_extension(mimetype)
```

Comment: Maybe `known_extension.get(mimetype, guess_extension(mimetype)`. Otherwise there are two problems: dict is not callable, and unknown extensions would raise a KeyError instead of evaluating the right-hand side.

Comment: Fixed (differently) above. Yours will work, but involves a possibily unnecessary call to guess_extension(). Probably doesn't matter in practice.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith you are right. Your solution works. But for me it is more a work-around. Not a solution.