# content-type text/plain has file extension .ksh?

Tags: python, mime-types

Python 2.7:

```
>>> from mimetypes import guess_extension
>>> guess_extension('text/plain')
'.ksh'
```

Python 3.5:

```
>>> from mimetypes import guess_extension
>>> guess_extension('text/plain')
'.c'
```

How can I get a valid answer?

For me ".txt" would fit.

Even the [filetype](https://pypi.org/project/filetype/) lib can't handle this :-(

See https://github.com/h2non/filetype.py/issues/30

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a more reliable drop-in replacement for mimetypes.guess\_extension()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447541/is-there-a-more-reliable-drop-in-replacement-for-mimetypes-guess-extension)

Comment: @EdHeal I only care about "text/plain" the other question is about a lot of other mime types.

Comment: Yes, there is roughly the same question already. But this has no valid answer. There is just a work around.

Comment: why not hard code those well known content types? i dont think you could get a valid answer with mimetypes lib.

Comment: @georgexsh yes, I could hard-code some well known mapping myself.  This way the same thing gets solved by developers over and over again. Hard coding works. I just want to avoid it, if possible. That's why I ask here.

Comment: @guettli IMHO it is impossible to establish criteria everyone could agree.

Comment: @georgexsh I think "text/plain" maps to ".txt" is something everyone could agree. There are several mappings which have a sane default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

although the question mentioned `mimetypes.guess_extension`, but it actually cannot be answered with the information in that module. mime type to extension mapping is one to multi, there is no weight info in the `mimetypes` database, sorting extensions by alphabetical order could give a consistent answer, but apparently not what OP wants. I considered the following options:

- by authority, [IANA DB](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) does not have extension information for every
  type, only a few types have this info and need hard work to parse.
- by popularity, I hope there is one.
- by consensus, an MDN wiki page named ["Incomplete list of MIME types"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) is most close: it is actively maintained, it lists only one extension for some well-known mime type.

I guess the practical solution is, grab the table from the aforementioned MDN wiki, hard code those types, use `mimetypes.guess_extension` as a fallback.

note you should take care of [MDN content license](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/About#Copyrights_and_licenses).

Answer (score 6):

To get consistent outputs with Python 3 and 2, you need to use `guess_all_extensions` and sort the output:

```
>>> from mimetypes import guess_all_extensions
>>> sorted(guess_all_extensions('text/plain'))
['.asc', '.bat', '.c', '.cc', '.conf', '.cxx', '.el', '.f90', '.h', '.hh', '.hxx', '.ksh', '.log', '.pl', '.pm', '.text', '.txt']
```

`.txt` is the last item.

It's kinda odd these aren't already sorted since `guess_extension` just takes [the first arbitrary extension](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7e18deef652a9d413d5dbd19d61073ba7eb5460e/Lib/mimetypes.py#L195), hence the different outputs you observe.